# I need a VBA to add unique value in row into column

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a VBA to automate adding unique values in a row to Column D. I currently have a macro that counts the unique values in the row and adds that amount of blank rows above.

If Column C has a value >0, list all unique values in R:AQ in Column D. The row range should be R:AQ.

I have added a before and after of what I would like the macro to do. Thank you!

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVSKZ.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMyYR.png)

Comment: Thanks for telling us what you want. Now show us what you have tried by including your code in your question, and explain where you ran into trouble. Please understand that Stack Overflow is not a website you go to with a need/want and expect other people to write all the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

### Unique Row Values to Column

- The insertion of the rows, writing to column `C`, and writing of the unique values should be done in the same procedure (with the help of accompanying procedures). You're kind of acquiring the unique values twice: when counting and when writing, risking to get different results. Sharing your 'insertion' code is therefore crucial.
- The following solution will only work correctly if the values in column `C` are correct. If there are more unique values than indicated in column `C`, it will still work, but only the first number of unique values indicated in column `C` will be written. If there are fewer unique values than indicated in column `C`, a message box with the current error description will appear: it will not work.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WriteUnique()
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    If lRow < 2 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, "C"), ws.Cells(lRow, "C"))
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = lrg.Rows.Count
    Dim lData As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim lData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): lData(1, 1) = lrg.Value
    Else
        lData = lrg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim urg As Range: Set urg = lrg.EntireRow.Columns("R:AQ")
    Dim ucCount As Long: ucCount = urg.Columns.Count
    Dim uData As Variant: uData = urg.Value
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    Dim tDat As Variant
    
    Dim r As Long: r = rCount
    Dim uCount As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    Do Until r < 2
        uCount = lData(r, 1)
        If uCount > 0 Then
            tDat = ArrUniqueRow(uData, r)
            If Not IsEmpty(tDat) Then
                r = r - uCount
                For n = 0 To uCount - 1
                    dData(r + n, 1) = tDat(n)
                Next n
            End If
        End If
        r = r - 1
    Loop
    
    ws.Cells(2, "D").Resize(rCount).Value = dData

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the unique values from a row ('RowNumber')
'               of a 2D one-based array ('Data') to a 1D zero-based array,
'               excluding error values and blanks.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function ArrUniqueRow( _
    ByVal Data As Variant, _
    ByVal RowNumber As Long, _
    Optional ByVal CompareMethod As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) _
As Variant
    
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then Exit Function
    If RowNumber < 0 Then Exit Function
    If RowNumber > UBound(Data, 1) Then Exit Function
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = CompareMethod
        
        Dim Key As Variant
        Dim c As Long
        For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Key = Data(RowNumber, c)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    .Item(Key) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        Next c
        If .Count = 0 Then Exit Function
        
        ArrUniqueRow = .Keys
    
    End With

End Function
```